# Feasibility of a motorized 3-axis gimbal for visualization

Tags: design, motors

Recently some friends and I conceived of a method for visualizing in real-time the pitch/yaw/roll of an aircraft where a model aircraft is mounted inside a gimbal; then, the controller for the gimbal would receive telemetry from a flight simulator and update the position of the aircraft to show you how steep the aircraft is climbing or what compass direction it is heading. (see [this diagram for an idea of what we are talking about.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Gimbal_lock_airplane.gif)) Not free-floating, but with a motor at each axle to keep the position correct.

We began our search for this by scouring the internet but haven't found any examples of a motorized gimbal like this. There are several difficulties we have encountered in designing our own, also.

What is a safe and effective way to translate control signals and power through an axle so that the inner gimbal ring motors will receive enough power to turn a balance 3D model on all axes? We considered wireless communication for the motors and using batteries but the batteries would add a lot of weight to each ring which would need to be balanced out.

Also, has this idea already been proposed and dismissed for being impractical? I don't want to reinvent the wheel (no pun intended) but also don't know the correct search terms to find a product like this.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me,

Comment: You can end up in a gimbal lock. But this would really only happen if you try to visualize a fighter jet or a acrobatics plane. You should be able to use similar ultrasonic motors on the rings as cameras use.

Comment: Right. I am not sure whether we could reduce the likelihood of a gimbal lock using a heuristic or not.

Comment: Not if you need to follow the planes orientation over time.